# PyQT5 + Python. How can I call a script when I press a button?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I want to a script run when I press a button through PyQT.
This is an example of my of buttons I created

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QPushButton, QApplication

class AutoTestWindow(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.initUI()


    def initUI(self):

        btn1 = QPushButton("Test № 1 ", self)
        btn1.move(30, 50)

        btn2 = QPushButton("Test № 2", self)
        btn2.move(150, 50)

        btn1.clicked.connect(self.buttonClicked)
        btn2.clicked.connect(self.buttonClicked)

        self.statusBar()

        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 290, 150)
        self.setWindowTitle('Запуск тестов')
        self.show()


    def buttonClicked(self):

        sender = self.sender()
        self.statusBar().showMessage(sender.text() + ' test started')


if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = AutoTestWindow()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: Buttons]
And this is a script I wanna run then the button is pressed. It's a auto test that opens a browser and does something.

```
def init_driver():
  driver =   webdriver.Chrome("/Users/alexeynikitin/Desktop/chromedriver")
  driver.wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 5)
  return driver


def findelem(driver, query):
  driver.get("https://www.yandex.ru/")
  try:
      box = driver.wait.until(ec.presence_of_element_located(
        (By.ID, "text")))
      button = driver.wait.until(ec.visibility_of_element_located(
        (By.CLASS_NAME, "search2__button")))
      box.send_keys(query)
      suggestion_box =  driver.wait.until(ec.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "body > div.i-bem.popup.suggest2.suggest2_theme_flat.suggest2_size_m.suggest2_adaptive_yes.suggest2_type_advanced.suggest2_ahead_yes.popup_adaptive_yes.popup_animate_no.popup_autoclosable_yes.popup_theme_ffffff.suggest2-detect_js_inited.suggest2_js_inited.popup_js_inited.popup_to_bottom.popup_visibility_visible")))
      try:
          button.click()   
      except ElementNotVisibleException:
          button = driver.wait.until(ec.visibility_of_element_located(
        (By.CLASS_NAME, "search2__button")))

  except TimeoutException:
    print("ничего не нашел на https://www.yandex.ru/")

 if __name__ == "__main__":
  driver = init_driver()
  findelem(driver, "Тензор")
  time.sleep(10)
  driver.quit()
```

That should I do to make it happen? I tried to call a function when a button is pressed, but it didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QPushButton, QApplication, QStatusBar

class AutoTestWindow(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.driver = None                      # +++         
        self.query  = "Тензор"                  # +++

        self.initUI()


    def initUI(self):

        btn1 = QPushButton("Test № 1 ", self)
        btn1.move(30, 50)

        btn2 = QPushButton("Test № 2", self)
        btn2.move(150, 50)

        #btn1.clicked.connect(self.buttonClicked)                                     # ---
        #btn2.clicked.connect(self.buttonClicked)                                     # ---
        btn1.clicked.connect(self.init_driver)                                        # +++
        btn2.clicked.connect(lambda checked : self.findelem(self.driver, self.query)) # +++

        self.statusBar().showMessage('Запуск тестов', 5000)

        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 290, 150)
        self.setWindowTitle('Запуск тестов')
        self.show()

    # ---
    #def buttonClicked(self):
    #    sender = self.sender()
    #    self.statusBar().showMessage(sender.text() + ' test started')

    # +++
    def init_driver(self):
        self.statusBar().showMessage('Test № 1  test started')
        #driver           = webdriver.Chrome("/Users/alexeynikitin/Desktop/chromedriver")
        self.driver     = webdriver.Chrome()
        self.driver.wait = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10)
        #return self.driver

    # +++
    def findelem(self, driver, query):
        print("\ndriver=`{}`, \nquery=`{}`\n".format(driver, query))
        self.statusBar().showMessage('Test № 2  test started')
        if driver is not None:  
            driver.get("https://www.yandex.ru/")
            try:
                box = driver.wait.until(ec.presence_of_element_located(
                                        (By.ID, "text")))
                button = driver.wait.until(ec.visibility_of_element_located(
                                           (By.CLASS_NAME, "search2__button")))
                box.send_keys(query)
                suggestion_box =  driver.wait.until(ec.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "body > div.i-bem.popup.suggest2.suggest2_theme_flat.suggest2_size_m.suggest2_adaptive_yes.suggest2_type_advanced.suggest2_ahead_yes.popup_adaptive_yes.popup_animate_no.popup_autoclosable_yes.popup_theme_ffffff.suggest2-detect_js_inited.suggest2_js_inited.popup_js_inited.popup_to_bottom.popup_visibility_visible")))
                try:
                    button.click()   
                except ElementNotVisibleException:
                    button = driver.wait.until(ec.visibility_of_element_located(
                                               (By.CLASS_NAME, "search2__button")))

            except TimeoutException:
                print("ничего не нашел на https://www.yandex.ru/")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex  = AutoTestWindow()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0):

If i correctly understood your question, it should be enough to connect the clickbutton event to the correct function when you initialize the class (or in your `initUI` method):

```
def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()
    self.initUI()

    btn1.clicked.connect(init_driver)
    btn2.clicked.connect(lambda checked :findelem(value1, value2))
```

I corrected the 2nd bind as @eyllanesc suggested

Comment: `btn2.clicked.connect(findelem(value1, value2))`??  
You are evaluating the function, which is incorrect. Use `btn2.clicked.connect(lambda checked :findelem(value1, value2))`

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to call a python script is to use `os`.
Assuming your script is located in same folder than your application, you need to add `import os`, then call `os.system('yourscriptname.py')` in your function `buttonClicked`.